# what does (return +1) mean in windows API buffer annotation?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

What does `return + 1` mean [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/header-annotations)

```
DWORD
WINAPI
GetModuleFileName(
    __in_opt HMODULE hModule,
    __out_ecount_part(nSize, return + 1) LPTSTR lpFilename,
    __in DWORD nSize
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal) annotations are generally built as combinations of primitives. `__out_ecount_part`, specifically, denotes a parameter that the function writes output through (`_out`). Indices index into elements as opposed to bytes (`_ecount`), and the function only writes to part of the buffer (`_part`).

The final two arguments in the annotation denote the buffer's total size and initialized length (on return). The total size is simple, as that value has a name (`nSize`). The initialized length, however, is the return value of the function, which doesn't have a name. SAL uses `return` to refer to it.

`return + 1` thus states that, on return, the buffer has been filled from the start up to (but not including) the index one past the function's return value. The `+ 1` accounts for the zero-terminator, the most common encoding for strings in C.

Note that SAL annotations are evaluated by static code analyzer tools only. None of this is meaningful to a C or C++ compiler. SAL annotations are implemented as preprocessor macros and get fully purged during pre-processing. This allows the use of otherwise reserved keywords (such as `return`).

Answer (score 4):

It means "one more than the value returned by the call".  `__out_ecount_part` annotation wants its *length* expression to include the NUL terminator, and the `GetModuleFileName` return value doesn't include the terminator, so `+1` to account for the difference.

> If the function succeeds, the return value is the length of the string that is copied to the buffer, in characters, not including the terminating null character.

Comment: @A.Agan All this `__out_ecount_part` stuff is [SAL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 3):

In "C" all strings are '\0' terminated. so the +1 allows for that extra '\0' at the end of the filename